# Can I change Git global config on Azure DevOps

Tags: git, configuration, azure-devops, settings

Our developers have a custom driver for git installed

`git config --global merge.ours.driver true`

This is used to allow us to ignore certain folders on when we merge from one branch to another.

We then include in our `.gitattributes` file:

```
**/Migrations/* merge=ours
**/MigrationsSql/* merge=ours
```

This works locally for our developers, however, we have since realized that when we run Pull Requests on DevOps and we hit the "Complete" button, because the driver we created on the developer machines is not on DevOps, these migration folders we were hoping to ignore would get merged too.

I have looked through the settings on DevOps and can't see any way to update the git config files there, so we can add this driver.

Does anyone know how\if I can update Azure DevOps git config to add this driver?

Comment: do you have these drivers installed and configured on your Build Agent boxes?
the fetch pull/ push is controlled by the build agents not by the devops server. I would suggest perhaps looks at your agent and see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't.

In general, if you don't want something to be managed by source control, don't put it in source control. Use a `.gitignore` to exclude it entirely.

Comment: Sadly that won’t work for us. We need branch specific changes in those folders, we just don’t want the migrations to merge across the branches.

Comment: @daniel-mann are there any news? In latest Azure DevOps version(s)?